# Reversing scroll direction across Synergy connection

Tags: linux, macos, synergy, xfce

I am running synergys on an XFCE desktop, with the scroll direction reversed (to provide "natural" scrolling, as I prefer these days). I am running synergyc on a Mac laptop running Snow Leopard (as we cannot upgrade to Lion at work for some reason) and Scroll Reverser. The reversed scroll events from XFCE stay reversed when sent to the Mac, and then on the Mac they get reversed again, causing them to be un-reversed.

For now I can simply turn Scroll Reverser on and off when I switch between using it as a synergy client and as a laptop, but I'd rather not have to do this.  Are there any configuration options in synergy.conf that allow me to reverse the scroll button (Button4/Button5) events like there are for the modifier keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually Scroll Reverser has a setting for that, it is just not added in the GUI... From the FAQ on [their website](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/):

> **I am controlling a machine via remote desktop, and Scroll Reverser is running on both the local and remote machine. Anything I can do to make it work nicely?** Run this command at terminal on the remote machine: `defaults write com.pilotmoon.scroll-reverser ReverseOnlyRawInput -bool YES` then quit and restart Scroll Reverser.

For my setup (Win 7 server controlling a Mac client using Sroll Reverser) this works like a charm.

Comment: Very nice! I no longer use Scroll Reverser (since OSX and Xfce both support natural scrolling now, and Windows has WizMouse) but this is definitely useful for people who do.

Comment: This trick also works when using Synergy from Windows to Mac and Scroll Reverser is only installed on the Mac. Awesome sauce.

Answer (score 3):

A partial answer which happens to work for my situation is to simply configure ScrollReverser to only reverse the trackpad; this seems to not re-reverse external mouse events, and in this particular case I will only be using the trackpad when I'm using the laptop as a laptop.  However, this isn't a full solution, as it means that if I ever do use a mouse on-the-go I'll have to still fiddle with the settings.

Comment: Stuck with the same problem. I continue to toggle the 'Reverse Mouse' option. At home I use an external mouse and at work I use synergy.