# Reverse scrolling with Synergy from Mac to Windows

Tags: windows-7, macos, mouse, scrolling, synergy

I have my *Mountain Lion MacBook Pro* and my *Windows 7 Toshiba* laptop connected via *Synergy* with the Mac serving as the server, and the PC acting as the client. I have an external mouse connected to the Mac with Scroll Reverser running to give my Mac traditional (aka non-natural) scrolling.

When I move my cursor from my Mac over to my PC and use the external mouse's scroll wheel to scroll, unfortunately the direction is reversed (i.e. it has "natural" scrolling, which doesn't feel so natural with a scroll wheel). None of the Scroll Reverser settings seem to give me what I want.

Any recommended ways to get regular scrolling when transmitting the Mac's mouse to the PC?

Comment: I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/382024/reversing-scroll-direction-across-synergy-connection), but it doesn't seem to be relevant to my case.